# How to extract email address from a text file with Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I'd like to know which is the simplest and most elegant way to process a text file with email addresses in it and extract them using Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my own attempt at it:

```
scala> import scala.io.Source.fromFile

scala> val r = """(?i)\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b""".r

scala> fromFile("./mails").getLines.flatMap { r.findAllIn _ }.toList
res29: List[String] = List(address@domain.com, anotheraddress@domain.com, address2@domain.com)
```

[Source for the RegEx.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Comment: this should be included in your question!

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ: not really. I suppose it's a valid answer, OP can even self-accept it if he finds it best.

Comment: your regexp will fail on some addresses (example@foo.bar.baz, info@louvre.museum, etc.). Check out [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

Comment: Youŕe right, peter, thanks for the link, that's exactly where I got the regExp from (will add that to the answer)